# Last element in scroll view requiring double click to be triggered

Tags: android, android-layout

I know this looks similar to other issues, but since I find it a pretty peculiar behaviour, I'm hoping somebody will explain **WHY** is this happening.

Basically it's the known problem of a clickable needing to be clicked twice before triggering the `onClick` code.
The puzzling bit is that it's happening only inside *ONE* of many instances of the same nested layout.
Let's see...

I have the following main layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgBanner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".80"
    android:src="@drawable/banner" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".20" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/panContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMainTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="xxx" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMainSubtitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="xxx" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

So, banner + scroll with title + subtitle.
In this scroll I want to insert some entries, formatted with the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtSynopsis"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnAction"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgCover" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgCover"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAction"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgCover"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgCover"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imgCover"
    android:text="Download" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgFade"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtSynopsis"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtSynopsis"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtSynopsis"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/fade_down" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgMore"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgFade"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgFade"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgFade"
    android:onClick="showMore"
    android:src="@drawable/show_more" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgLess"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgFade"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgFade"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtSynopsis"
    android:layout_marginTop="-12dip"
    android:onClick="showLess"
    android:src="@drawable/show_less"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Which would be:

- title on top
- on the left: book's cover + download button (below it)
- on the right: synopsis, cut to the bottom of the download button, with an image to make it appear fading into the background (imgFade) and a button to "show more" (plus the button to "show less" which remains hidden)

In the `onCreate` method I'm adding some content to the `panContent` element, this way:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LinearLayout panContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.panContent);
    for (EntryModel m : this.entries) {
        ViewGroup g = new LinearLayout(this);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.entry, g);
        /* ... populating data in the TextView and ImageView ... */
        panContent.addView(g);
    }
}
```

Lastly, here are the `onClick` handlers:

```
public void showMore(View v) {
    RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) v.getParent();

    View txt = container.findViewById(R.id.txtSynopsis);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams sLayout =
        (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) txt.getLayoutParams();
    sLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, 0);

    container.findViewById(R.id.imgFade).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    container.findViewById(R.id.imgLess).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    txt.setLayoutParams(sLayout);
}

public void showLess(View v) {
    RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) v.getParent();

    View txt = container.findViewById(R.id.txtSynopsis);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams sLayout =
        (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) txt.getLayoutParams();
    sLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, R.id.btnAction);

    container.findViewById(R.id.imgFade).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    container.findViewById(R.id.imgMore).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    txt.setLayoutParams(sLayout);
}
```

Basically:

- when I click the "show more" image, unbind `txtSynopsis`' bottom (so that it spans how many rows it wants to), hide the image (and fade mask) and show the "show less" image;
- when clicking "show less", well, restore things.

Here we go. This is working flawlessly (almost...) for EVERY SINGLE ENTRY, but the LAST one!!!
What happens with that one is:

- I have to click TWICE on "show more", to have it work,
- I have to click TWICE on "show less",
- then it's enough to click just ONCE on "show more", but
- I still need to click TWICE on "show less"!

Thank you everybody, any help and useful insight greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Insure that your view isn't focusable